# FCM - Android notification not work after some time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am backend developer, I am working on one app with my friend, we are facing issues like notification is not coming from nodejs, from fcm console with topics, after clear data or reinstall app and login it's working fine but again after some weeks cycle is repeated. Is there have any solution?

Comment: Some time FCM token expired, tell your friend to check the onNewToken() method in FirebaseMessagingService which return the updated FCM token.

Comment: Thanks, @Sniffer, but we are using FCM notification by /topics/ not by token

Comment: You must use token...

Comment: Okay @sniffer, Thanks